# Calculating daily mean of data measured four time a day for years from netcdf file?

Tags: python, python-xarray

So the data I have is as follows:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
temperature = xr.open_dataset("./Temperature/merged_temp.nc")
temp = temperature.sel(time=slice('1954-04-07', '1957-04-07'))
print(temp)

Out[1]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 73, lon: 144, time: 4388)
Coordinates:   * lon      (lon) float32 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 10.0 ... 350.0 352.5 355.0 357.5
               * lat      (lat) float32 90.0 87.5 85.0 82.5 80.0 ... -82.5 -85.0 -87.5 -90.0
               * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1954-04-07 ... 1957-04-07T18:00:00
Data variables:
               air      (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
Attributes:
Conventions:    COARDS
title:          4x daily NMC reanalysis (1950)
description:    Data is from NMC initialized reanalysis\n(4x/day). These...
```

The data is distributed 4 times a day (i.e. the variable 'air; is measured four times daily)

```
temp.sel(time='1954-04-07')
Out[2]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 73, lon: 144, time: 4)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float32 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 10.0 ... 350.0 352.5 355.0 357.5
  * lat      (lat) float32 90.0 87.5 85.0 82.5 80.0 ... -82.5 -85.0 -87.5 -90.0
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1954-04-07 ... 1954-04-07T18:00:00
Data variables:
    air      (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
Attributes:
    Conventions:    COARDS
    title:          4x daily NMC reanalysis (1950)
    description:    Data is from NMC initialized reanalysis\n(4x/day).  These...
    platform:       Model
```

The variable 'air' is measured 4 times a day from **1954-04-07** to **1957-04-07**. I want the same data but instead of these four measurements I want to average out the value of 'air' on daily basis. How can I do it in Python?

I have used the following for my problem.

- Python 3.6
- Anaconda 4.7

Comment: Note: I have already tried ```temp.resample(time='1d').mean()``` but it takes ridiculously long to produce the results.

Comment: How long is ridiculously long?  The resample method seems like it should be the way to go here and I imagine it only taking a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
temp.resample(time='1D').mean(dim='time')
```

It is very true that it takes a long time, be patient.